# connect to remote sql server database using python from linux with windows auth

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, pymssql

I have an MS SQL Server running on my server machine,
i want to connect to the server using python running on my linux machine.

i have tried to use `pyodbc`

```
connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
'Server=ip;'
'Database=db;'
'Trusted_Connection=True;')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

and with `pymssql` i got this issue

```
>>> import pymssql
>>> conn = pymssql.connect(server="ip", user="user", password="password", database="database")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/pymssql.pyx", line 636, in pymssql.connect
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1964, in _mssql.connect
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 682, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1690, in _mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException
_mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (18456, b"Login failed for user 'user'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (ip)\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (ip)\n")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "src/pymssql.pyx", line 642, in pymssql.connect
pymssql.OperationalError: (18456, b"Login failed for user 'user'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (ip)\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (ip)\n")
```

Comment: Have you installed, configured and enabled Kerberos on your Linux host?

Comment: no, i am not aware of it.
is that necessary to have windows auth?or is there any other way where i can use sql user auth instead.?

Comment: *"is that necessary to have windows auth?"* Yep. And no, you don't need it for SQL Authentication; the 2 are completely different authentication methods.

Comment: pymssql [works for me](https://pastebin.com/NvnLsTDw)

Comment: @Larnu - Kerberos is required for Microsoft's ODBC drivers (msodbcsql*.so), but not for pymssql or [FreeTDS ODBC](https://pastebin.com/ueQBQ3bE).